# JNI's "Invalid memory access of location.."

Tags: java, c++, macos, debugging, java-native-interface

I have some code written in C++, let's call it A. It contains some nested functions, so that to make a binary out of A, I needed to use -fnested-functions flag.

Now I need to make a .jnilib library out of A, so that it can be invoked from Java. However, I go the error:

> Invalid memory access of location 0x105... rip=0x105..

I could not figure out what the cause is (I tried to include the -fnested-functions flag when linking to create the .jnilib library, but g++ does not allow it).

Has anyone ran into this problem before, or could kindly suggest how to debug (core dump) this problem?

I'm running MacOS Lion, with the built-in Java.

Comment: The message says that your code tries to call some code at 0x105..., but there is nothing there. So, how did you end up there? What does the call look like?

Comment: i traced the code back (by printing out stuff), at this is happening when it tries to call a nested function. When I compiling a binary out of A, I got Segmentation Fault at the exact same place, but that was solved by using the -fnested-functions flags. But this flag did not work when compiling A into a shared library.

Comment: right, so it turns out to be a real problem with support for nested function in newer versions of Mac OS, for they use Clang compiler that does not like nested function. The solution is to download and apply the patch at (http://ds.cs.rwth-aachen.de/members/bitsch/pbc-0.5.4-osx.patch). There's small error when compiling, but fixing that is pretty straightforward.